# Dependency conflicts in asp.net core on mac

Tags: dependencies, asp.net-core, project.json

I am new to .NET and I don't know how to debug these kind of troubles when it comes to dependencies. I am trying to run a dotnet core application in mac, below you can see the output of the terminal when I execute **dotnet restore**  and later you can see my `project.json`. I am not sure what kind of information will be helpful here. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks.

```
log  : Restoring packages for /Users/dimitris/Develop/JustBringCore/src/JustBringCore/project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools' in /Users/dimitris/Develop/JustBringCore/src/JustBringCore/project.json...
error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in /Users/dimitris/Develop/JustBringCore/src/JustBringCore/project.json...
error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 supports:
error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' in /Users/dimitris/Develop/JustBringCore/src/JustBringCore/project.json...
error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 supports:
error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools' in /Users/dimitris/Develop/JustBringCore/src/JustBringCore/project.json...
info :   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.dotnethostresolver/index.json
info :   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.dotnethost/index.json
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools' in /Users/dimitris/Develop/JustBringCore/src/JustBringCore/project.json...
error: Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration 1.0.0-preview2-final is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration 1.0.0-preview2-final supports:
error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
error: Project JustBringUtils is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Project JustBringUtils supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
error: Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 1.0.0 supports:
error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
error: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 supports:
error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
error: Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 1.0.0-preview2-final is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 1.0.0-preview2-final supports:
error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 supports:
error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
error: Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration 1.0.0-preview2-final is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration 1.0.0-preview2-final supports:
error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
error: One or more projects are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
info : Committing restore...
log  : Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: /Users/dimitris/Develop/JustBringCore/src/JustBringCore/project.lock.json
log  : /Users/dimitris/Develop/JustBringCore/src/JustBringCore/project.json
log  : Restore failed in 6812ms.

Errors in /Users/dimitris/Develop/JustBringCore/src/JustBringCore/project.json
    Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
    Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
    - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
    - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
    Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 supports:
    - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
    - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
    Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
    - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
    - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
    Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 supports:
    - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
    - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
    Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration 1.0.0-preview2-final is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration 1.0.0-preview2-final supports:
    - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
    - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
    Project JustBringUtils is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Project JustBringUtils supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
    Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 1.0.0 supports:
    - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
    - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 supports:
    - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
    - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
    Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 1.0.0-preview2-final is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 1.0.0-preview2-final supports:
    - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
    - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
    Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
    Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
    - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
    - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
    Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 supports:
    - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
    - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
    Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration 1.0.0-preview2-final is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration 1.0.0-preview2-final supports:
    - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
    - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
    One or more projects are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.

NuGet Config files used:
    /Users/dimitris/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

**project.json**

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-JustBringCore-...",

  "dependencies": {
    "CsvHelper": "2.16.0",
    "JustBringUtils": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Stripe.net": "6.3.5"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `dotnet restore` is dumping out a bunch of errors, there's a few things you can check.

First, make sure you are using the latest version of `dotnet`:

```
λ dotnet --version
1.0.0-preview2-003121
```

Next, you can start removing the offending packages one by one to determine which ones are breaking the restore. With a few tweaks, I was able to successfully restore with this **project.json**:

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-JustBringCore-...",

  "dependencies": {
    "CsvHelper": "2.16.0",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Stripe.net": "6.3.5"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.4",
        "portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

In your original file, `Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools` was one version out of date.